# How to use auh with Twitter trends

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to use Twitter Trends, but not limited to the last ten trends. However I do not understand the API.

My basic code is...

```
$woeid = 2459115;
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/".$woeid.".json", true);
$decode = json_decode($json, false);
$data = $decode[0]->trends; 
foreach ($data as $item) {
...
}
```

When i create an app with Twitter, I see...

*Signature base string... Authorization header... cURL command...*

with

*Request type: GET Request URI: https://api.twitter.com/1/*

But how to deal with this?

Thanks,

V.

Answer (score 1):

No, the API itself returns **only 10** trends. It doesn't require creating an app, or authentication to return more trends, the trends API is public.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3Awoeid
Returns the top 10 trending topics for a specific WOEID, if trending information is available for it.

Edit: Yeah your code is correct.

Comment: Thanks Mob. I thought more than ten results with authentication. "Only 10 trends", I'm an ass. :)